# Qt:How to tell Qmake to include ws2_32 in visual studio project

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

Hello all
im using some third party lib in side Qt application
but i like the *.pro file and the QMAKE to be the default .
how can i tell qmake (what to write in the *.pro file ) to include in my visual studio   project the windows ws2_32 socket lib
in the include lib dir ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `QMAKE_LIBS += ws2_32.lib` in your .pro file.